# calling a javascript function in {{if}} of jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

have a  javascript function as follows:

```
function test(item) {
       var DataToBeShownOnScreen = jQuery.data(document.body, "DataTobeShown");
       var found = $.inArray(item, DataToBeShownOnScreen) > -1;
       return found;
}
```

and I need to call this function in my jquery template as follows:

```
<script id="GridTemplate" type="text/html">
     <tbody>            
         {{each Data}} 
             <tr>
               {{each $value}} 
               {{if ${test($index)} }}                   
                   <td>${$value}</td>
               {{/if}}
               {{/each}}
             </tr>
          {{/each}} 
     </tbody>
</script>
```

But I am getting error:

> expected identifier, string or number

I want help in understanding what is the mistake i am doing in the call of function test in the `{{if}}` of my template.

Comment: looks like you're missing a curly bracket after `{{/if}`

Comment: have you tried `{{if test($index)}}` ?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind {{/if}} i have corrected , it was only a typo in the post. THe problem still perists.

Comment: @jbabey thanks your solution helped. The problem I guess was ${test($index)} would output a string rather than giving true or false as bool. ${} around the function meant I actually get the bool value. I should have guessed this. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer for others @TijoThomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using `{{if test($index)}}  instead of {{if ${test($index)}}}.`

The problem I guess was `${test($index)}` would output a string rather than giving `true` or `false` as `bool`. Removing `${}` around the function meant that I actually get the bool value.